# Finding joint PDF of $\max$ and $\min$ of $n$ iid random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

**The Problem:** Suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent random variables with the same absolutely continuous distribution. Let $f$ denote their common marginal PDF. Set $Y=\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ 
and $Z=\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. Find the joint PDF of $(Y,Z)$.

**My Attempt:** First we find the joint CDF. For any $y,z\in\mathbb R$ we have that
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
F_{YZ}((y,z))&=P(Y\leq y,Z\leq z)\\
&=P(\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)\leq y,\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)\leq z)\\
&=P(\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)\leq y,X_1\leq z,\dots,X_n\leq z)\\
&=[1-P(X_1>y)\cdots P(X_n>y)]F(z)^n\\
&=[1-(1-F(y))^n]F(z)^n,
\end{split}\end{equation*}
where in the fourth step we used the independence of the random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and the fact that $P(A\cap B)=[1-P(A^\complement)]P(B)$ for any independent events $A,B$. By the 
absolute continuity of the random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ we may differentiate the expression for $F_{YZ}$ to obtain the joint PDF of $(Y,Z)$,
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
f_{YZ}(y,z)&=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial z}[1-(1-F(y))^n]F(z)^n\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}nf(z)[1-(1-F(y))^n]F(z)^{n-1}\\
&=n^2f(z)f(y)F(z)^{n-1}(1-F(y))^{n-1}\\
\end{split}\end{equation*}

---

Do you agree with my solution above? Any feedback is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind that $Y,Z$ are NOT independent. 
$$ P(Y<y,Z<z) = P(Z<z)- P(Y>y, Z<z) = P\bigg( \bigcap_i \{X_i<z\}\bigg)- P\bigg(\bigcap_i \{X_i\in [y,z]\} \bigg) = \ F(z)^n- (F(z)-F(y))^n  $$
Taking the derivative w.r.t to $y$ and $z$ yields
$$ f_{Y,Z}(y,z)= \partial_y (nF(z)^{n-1}f(z) -n(F(z)-F(y))^{n-1} f(z)) = n(n-1)(F(z)-F(y))^{n-2}f(z)f(y) $$

Comment: Does the first step follow because $\{Z\leq z\}=\{Y\leq y,Z\leq z\}\cup\{Y>y,Z\leq z\}$ is a union of disjoint events?

Comment: yes, exactly. And due to the absolute continuity it doesn't matter if you write $\le$ or $<$.