# Joint CDF and PDF of the maximum and minimum of three i.i.d. Unif(0,1) random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

I have a question about the following problem from Introduction to Probability.

**Problem**

> Let $U_1, U_2, U_3$ be i.i.d. $\text{Unif}(0, 1)$, and let $L = \min(U_1, U_2, U_3)$, $M =\max(U_1, U_2, U_3)$. (a) Find the marginal CDF and marginal PDF of $M$, and the joint CDF and joint PDF of $L, M$.
> Hint: for the latter, start by considering $P(L<l,M>m)$.

**Attempt at a Solution**

Following the hint,

$$P(L<l,M>m) = (1-m)(l)(1)$$

because at least one of the random variables must exceed $m$, which occurs with probability $1-m$, at least one must be less than $l$, which occurs with probability $l$, and the remaining random variable can have any value.

$$P(L>l,M>m) = (1-m)(1-l)(1)$$

because at least one of the random variables must exceed $m$ and of the remaining two at least one must exceed $l$.

Similarly, $$P(L>l,M<m) = (m-l)^3$$ since all the random variables must be between $l$ and $m$.

If these approaches are analogous, why is the expression for $P(L>l,M<m)$ correct but those for $P(L<l,M>m)$ and $P(L>l,M>m)$ incorrect?

I also tried other unsuccessful approaches, for example,

$$P(L>l,M>m) = (1-m)(1-l^2)(1)$$

because at least one of the random variables must exceed $m$ and of the remaining two at least one must exceed $l$ and

$$P(\text{ both of the remaining two RVs }<l) = l^2. $$

so

$$P(\text{ at least one of the remaining two RVs }>l) =1-l^2. $$

Comment: $P(L\gt l,M\lt m)+P(L\gt l.M\gt m)=P(L\gt l)=(1-l)^3$.  Yours don't add up.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054665/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3579827/321264.

Answer (score 1):

NB: assuming that $0<\ell<m<1$.

> Following the hint, $$P(L<l,M>m) = (1-m)(l)(1)$$
>
> because at least one of the random variables must exceed m, which occurs with probability 1-m, at least one must be less than l, which occurs with probability l, and the remaining random variable can have any value.

You have to count *distinct arrangements* of the samples.

So among the three samples you need to measure probabilities that:

- Two are below $\ell$ and one above $m$,
- One is below $\ell$, one above $m$, and one between those values.
- Two are above $m$ and one is below $\ell$.

$\begin{align}{\mathsf P(L<\ell, M>m)}&={\tbinom 32 \ell^2(1-m)+3! \ell(m-\ell)(1-m)+\tbinom 32 \ell(1-m)^2}\\[1ex]&=3\,\ell\,(1-m)\,(\ell+2(m-\ell)+(1-m))\\[1ex]&=3\,\ell\,(1-m)\,(1+m-\ell)\end{align}$

---

For the joint *pdf*, I would suggest adjusting your argument to say "$\{L=\ell,M=m\}$ is any outcome where: the samples are arranged ($3!$ ways) with the least at $\ell$, the greatest at $m$, and the middle anywhere between those two.".

$$\begin{align}f_{\small L,M}(\ell,m)&= 3! f(\ell)\,(F(m)-F(\ell))\,f(m)\\[1ex]&=6 (m-\ell) \end{align}$$

---

So by integration we also get...

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(L<\ell,M>m)&=\int_0^\ell\int_m^1 6\,(y-x)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&= \int_0^\ell 3\,(1^2-m^2)-6\,x\,(1-m)\,\mathrm d x\\&=3\,\ell\,(1-m^2)-3\,\ell^2\,(1-m)\\&=3\,\ell\,(1-m)\,(1+m-\ell) \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

(a) General formula for max/min of n i.i.d random variables:

$F_{min(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})}(x) = 1 - (1 - F_{X_{i}}(x))^n$

$F_{max(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})}(x) = F_{X_{i}}(x)^n$

$p_{min(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})}(x) = F_{min(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})}(x)^{\prime} = n(1 - F_{X_{i}}(x))^{n-1} \cdot p_{X_{i}}(x)$

$p_{max(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})}(x) = F_{max(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})}(x)^{\prime} = nF_{X_{i}}(x)^{n-1} \cdot p_{X_{i}}(x)$